# Trying to find a story called "The Curse of the Phantom Rolls Royce"

Tags: identification-request, short-stories

As a child (at 12 or 13, ~55 years ago) I read a story called "The Curse of the Phantom Rolls Royce" and I loved it. It wasn’t a big book so I think it was a stand alone story. I certainly don’t recall other stories around it. I don’t think the book was very old at the time but I certainly didn’t have a new copy. I only know this as I remember loving it but I can't remember anything else about it.

I've tried finding the book, but have found nothing with that title. Neither on the web or listed at the British Library (I assume it was a British book!)

Does it sound familiar to anyone?

Comment: The closest I got so far is a story (in a collection) titled ["The Phantom Car"](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Urban_Legends/vPWKU7hCG7EC?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=rolls%20royce) where the car in question in a Rolls-Royce, but I can't find that story anywhere else and thus can't date it or determine if it was printed alone.

Comment: Yes, it sounds familiar.  I remember it from the late '60s.  From memory it was a short story in an anthology, you probably need to hunt through some anthologies from that time.

Comment: That does sound a bit familiar. I'll dig around in that space.. Thanks for the hint.